# Creation of stored procedure is not executing

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table SalesDetails (
    DetailsId int primary key,
    SaleId varchar(6),
    Item varchar(10),
    Quantity int 
);

INSERT INTO SalesDetails VALUES('1234', 'DE230', 'Apple' , '6') ;
INSERT INTO SalesDetails VALUES('456', 'DE290', 'Pear' , '10') ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_details()
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM SalesDetails ;
END  
DELIMITER ;
```

Nothing is happening when I am executing the create procedure. I am using MySQL WorkBench.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE creates the procedure (sic!) but not executes it. And you must finalize creation code with new delimiter `//` and revert it back to `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close delimiter `END //`:

```
create table SalesDetails (
    DetailsId int primary key,
    SaleId varchar(6),
    Item varchar(10),
    Quantity int 
);

INSERT INTO SalesDetails VALUES('1234', 'DE230', 'Apple' , '6') ;
INSERT INTO SalesDetails VALUES('456', 'DE290', 'Pear' , '10') ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_details()
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM SalesDetails ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the stored procedure and see the output you have to call it.

```
CALL sp_details()
```